# Replacing null and undefined values in json value with empty("")

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'mm getting a JSON response with lots of `null` and `undefined` values. I need to replace all `null` and `undefined` values with an empty string (`""`). Below is a sample response I'm getting:

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

```
{
  lecCicode: null
  lecOrderNo: null
  loccType: "Z"
  nccrCode: null
  nciCode: null
},
{
  lecCicode: null
  lecOrderNo: null
  loccType: "Z"
  nccrCode: null
  nciCode: null
},
{
  lecCicode: null
  lecOrderNo: null
  loccType: "Z"
  nccrCode: null
  nciCode: null
}
```

Comment: `Array#forEach` with `Object.keys` ?

Comment: *"im getting json response with lots of null and undified value"* You might be getting `null`, but you definitely aren't getting `undefined`, as it doesn't exist in JSON.

Comment: What's your issue with `null` as value???

Comment: `DATA.forEach(function(item) {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
    item[key] = item[key] == null ? '' : item[key];
  })
});`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/04ucymf6/

Answer (score 6):

You can try like:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourjson).replace(/null/g, '""'))
```

Comment: And if the name of the key is `"null"` or if the value is `"I am null"` then ?

Comment: then above solution will not work, above solution only for replace null from values, like show in the question